# Hiding widgets in a QMainWindow layout with a translucent background on macOS

Tags: macos, qt, transparency, qlayout

Using Qt 6.5.1, I got QMainWindow with `WA_TranslucentBackground`. I want to hide and show some elements in its layout. It looks like the layout or background doesn't repaint after hiding the widget.

Before hiding `btn2`:
[image]

After hiding btn2:
[image]

I made a sample to demonstrate this:

MainWindow.h:

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "QtWidgets/qboxlayout.h"
#include "QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *btnsLayout;
    QPushButton *btn1;
    QPushButton *btn2;

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

  public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
        , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Window);
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);

        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn1", this);
        btn2 = new QPushButton("btn2", this);
        btnsLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
        btnsLayout->addWidget(btn1);
        btnsLayout->addWidget(btn2);

        connect(btn1, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onBtnClick);

        centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
        centralWidget->setLayout(btnsLayout);

        setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    }
    ~MainWindow() { delete ui; }

  public slots:
    void onBtnClick(bool)
    {
        btn2->hide();

        // works!
        // setVisible(false);
        // setVisible(true);
        //}
    }
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I'm ok with the layout moving `btn1`, but I need to get rid of the "shadows" of the buttons.

I tried `removeWidget`, `delete btn2`, `btnsLayout->update()`, `MainWindow::update()`, and `repaint`, nothing helps.

The only workaround I found is to hide and show the entire mainwindow, but I think there's a better way.

Comment: Just for your information, this works as you intend on Linux using Qt 6.6.1. The hidden button is completely invisible, no shadows.

Comment: Seems like a bug. Just to clarify, the commented section refers to the fact that if you hide and show the window, the "ghost" widgets disappear? What happens if the window is resized? Can you try to force an `update()` either on the window or the central widget (possibly with a QTimer.singleShot)? Note that there's no need to create widgets with the parent argument when they are going to be reparented anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 
musicamante, yes, the only option I found to get rid of "ghost" widgets is to hide and show the window. Resizing the window also helps, thank you, I will keep in mind this workaround. 
Tried to call `update()` on the window and central widget directly and using QTimer.singleShot, but no luck.

Comment: I was wondering maybe it has something to do with repainting of the window background since it only reproduces when the translucent flag is on. But I haven't figured out how to get to the background yet.

Comment: Yes, it's almost certainly related to that, but it may just be a symptom. Did you try to use `repaint()` instead of update? Have you tested different timeout intervals? I've checked https://bugreports.qt.io a bit, but I only found slightly related (and, theoretically, solved) issues. I'm not on macOS, though, so maybe you should do some research there on your own, and eventually consider filing a report.

Comment: Yes, I've tried `repaint()` and different timeout intervals too. Thanks for your suggestions. I've reported this issue on bugreports.qt.io, will see.